# 아니요, 남자아이는 여자가 아닙니다. Is this sentence gramatically correct with respect to the honorofics used?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, honorific

**아니요, 남자아이는 여자가 아닙니다** : Why would the sentence start with '**요** ' (아니요) and end with '**ㅂ니다**' (아닙니다)? I thought both were used in different levels of formality. Is it correct for the same sentence to use both of these endings?

Comment: It might be difficult to understand, but the *interjection* 아니요 and its antonyms 네 and 예 are relevant to politeness *not* formality levels. They are like "yes" and "no" one say to another "higher" in age, rank, etc. (You should also note that 아니요 means "yes" after a negative statement.)

Comment: It sounds totally fine. It is very common to use -요./-요? and -ㅂ니다./-ㅂ니까? at the same time, except for VERY formal situations or in formal writing, in which case you might want to avoid using -요.

Comment: Also note that use of -ㅂ니까? or excessive use of -ㅂ니다. makes you sound less friendly and more formal. Try to use -ㅂ니다. in 1/4~1/2 of your sentences, and stick to -요? when asking questions, if you want to sound natural, polite and not too formal.

Comment: @Absol Alternating 해요체 and 합쇼체 sometimes happens, but I do not think they are normally used in the same sentence.

Comment: @Klmo Of course they are not normally used in the same sentence, because they are located at the end of the sentence or at least need a comma after that. I meant that they are used together in a single conversation, paragraph, etc.

Comment: @Absol The OP asked about the use of both 요 and -ㅂ니다 in the same sentence. "그게 더 볼만했**습니다요**" is one direct example I can think of, although National Institute of Korean Language thinks that it is *incorrect* to attach 요 to -ㅂ니다 [(reference)](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=189329).

Comment: Well, I don't think that is what OP asked about. The sentence has a comma, which implies that it is basically two separate sentences merged into one. My interpretation is that what OP is really asking about is the consistency of formality about the same person in whole conversation rather than in a single sentence. In a single sentence without comma, one has only one instance of the endings like -요 and -ㅂ니다, so why would one ask about using two of them in such sentences?

Comment: @Absol The OP said "Is it correct for **the same sentence** to use both of these endings?" That is how she/he interprets the sentence given above. You should consider that everyone has their own perspectives. Some people think the interjection "no" is not a complete sentence while others think it is. Even if "no" can be a sentence, connecting clauses (sentences) makes a mixed sentence, which is also a single sentence.

Comment: I had a think about this: If "아니요" is a single sentence, what words are its subject and predicative verb/adjective? At least, I could not answer this. // Real examples like "... 2050년도에 가면**요** 정말 유년이 적고 노인 부양비가 월등하게 높아**집니다**" and "네 명이서 야근하면**요** 정말 사람 죽**습니다**" have no commas and both 요 and -ㅂ니다. They are just single sentences. The standard dictionary has "마음은**요** 더없이 좋아**요**." It shows that 요 can be used twice in a single sentence. It seems that 요 is more flexible about its position than -ㅂ니다.

Comment: @Klmo Check out this: https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=462398&searchKeywordTo=3  
표준국어대사전 lists uses of -요 like yours and mine separately. I believe you would agree with my explanations above if we restrict ourselves to the first type of use of -요 as listed in the link. All your examples are of the second type. 
Also, for OP, 표준국어대사전 lists "아니요" as a single word, not "아니"+ "-요" (though that should be its etymology), so you don't need to worry about that particular word.

Comment: I checked it out yesterday. In fact, I have thought that as an interjection, the word 아니요 in the OP's example belongs to neither 해요체 nor 합쇼체. NIKL mentioned: "'아니요'는 사전에 감탄사로 등재되어 있으므로 높임의 등급으로 말하기 어렵습니다. 물론, '아니/아니요'의 관계를 생각한다면 '아니요'를 '해요체'로 생각할 수 있지만, 사전에 품사로 설정되었다는 점에서 '아니요'를 **높임 등급으로 말하지 않습니다.**" Thus, the OP's question itself may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very formal situation, one may consistently use -합니다 for every sentence.  In other cases, one could also use -해요 for every sentence.  However, it's not unusual for these endings to appear together in the same paragraph.  (Appearing together in the same *sentence* might be less common, simply because a sentence usually only contains one such sentence ending - but see the comment thread above.)

Here's one example I found from a popular children's book (구름빵):

> "있잖아, 나 배고파." 동생이 **말했어요.**
>
> "하늘을 날아다녀서 그럴 거야. 우리, 구름빵 하나씩 더 먹을까?"
>
> 동생과 나는 구름빵을 또 **먹었어요.**
>
> 구름을 바라보며 먹는 구름빵은 정말 **맛있었습니다.**